# Change linewidth on canvas using slider in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I'm hoping someone can help. I'm doing a drawing app. I'm working on 
adjusting the line width on the canvas using the slider. If a user 
selects 2 on the slider then line width should be thin, 40 would be a 
very thick line.
Many thanks in advance,
Filipe

This is my HTML

```
<div id="theLineWidthSection" style="float:right; margin-right:170px; 
margin-top:-42px; position:relative;z-index:9999; cursor:pointer; 
overflow:hidden;">
Size: <input type="range" id="theLineWidth" min="2" max="40" 
value="2" title="Line width"> 
</div>
```

This is my Javascript

```
$('#theLineWidth').change(function () {
var canvas = document.getElementById('drawingCanvas');
var lineSize = document.getElementById('theLineWidth');
var mySize = lineSize.value;

lineSize.addEventListener('change', changeLineWidth);

function changeLineWidth(){
mySize = lineSize.value;
context.lineWidth = mySize;
context.lineWidth = lineSize.value;        
}    
});
```

When the slider is changed the linewidth doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not taking the canvas `context` before applying the line-width change. This should fix it:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('drawingCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext("2d")
var lineSize = document.getElementById('theLineWidth');
var mySize = lineSize.value;

$('#theLineWidth').change(function () {
mySize = lineSize.value;
context.lineWidth = mySize;      
});
```

Also, take your variables out of the function. There is no need of redefining them each time the `change` event is fired.

Answer (score 0):

This is a demo where I'm changing the linewidth on canvas using slider.
The event I'm using is `input` that fires when the value of input changes.

I hope it helps.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('drawingCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var mySize = 2;
//draw something on the canvas
draw();

theLineWidth.addEventListener("input",function () {
var mySize = theLineWidth.value;
// change the line width
context.lineWidth = mySize;

draw();
});


// a function that is drawing something on the canvas
function draw(){
//first clear the context
  context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  // next draw 
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(10,75);
  context.lineTo(290,75);
  context.stroke();
}
```

```css
#theLineWidthSection {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 170px;
  /* margin-top: -42px;*/
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline:1px solid;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
}

canvas{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<div>
Size: <input type="range" id="theLineWidth" min="2" max="40" 
value="2" title="Line width"> 
</div> 
<canvas id="drawingCanvas"></canvas>
```